# Отправка запроса без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax, javascript, java

Хотела отправить запрос, не перезагружая страницу. Использовала для этого ajax фрэймворк taconite. Посмотрела пример [оттуда](http://taconite.sourceforge.net/example2.html) и решила сделать точно так же. Но мне нужно отправить кое-какие данные и с помощью этих данных удалить некий объект в базе. То есть выбираешь и нажимаешь удалить, потом выходит окошко "Вы точно хотите удалить?", нажав да, он отправляет все данные об этом человеке (которого нужно удалить) и удаляет.

С помощью обычного jsp+servlet запрос отправляется и удаляется. Но мне нужно, чтобы страница не перезагружалась. Поэтому я делаю, как на примере, все получается. Только не знаю, как вставить часть, где должны удалится данные. Как вставить сам запрос delete?

Это отправка метода:

```
<form method="#">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<%=dataList5.get(5)%>"/>
        <center><p style="color: #fff;">Вы точно хотите удалить?</p>
            <a href="javascript:doEcho('echo.jsp');">Да</a>
            <a href="javascript:location.reload()" />Нет</a>
    </form>
```

А это сам echo.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/xml"%>

 <%
     String id = request.getParameter("id");
 %>
 <taconite-root xml:space="preserve">

 <taconite-replace-children contextNodeID="echoResponse">
 <%
  Connection con = null;
    Statement sql = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List dataList5 = new ArrayList();
       try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pod", "diana", "123456789");
sql = con.createStatement();
}catch(Exception e){

    out.print("ERROR IN CONNECTION" + e);
}

     String query = "delete from employee where id_people ='"+id+"'";
     try{
        try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
            s.executeUpdate(query);
            rs = s.getResultSet();

        }
         }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);
    }
 %>
     <div>
        Your id is: <%=id%>

    </div>

</taconite-replace-children>

 </taconite-root>
```

Так не работает. Помогите сделать правильно. Не обязательно taconite, подскажите, как иначе можно сделать без перезагрузки.

**Обновление**

[[@StixoTvorec](/users/25218/stixotvorec)](/users/25218/stixotvorec), Я сделала, но проще чем у вас, так как не поняла что означают строки после `success`, `error`
Сделала и вызвала метод `call()`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call() {
      var msg   = $('#fio');
        $.ajax({

          type: 'POST',
          action: 'delete',
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Удалено');
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Так вот здесь у меня выходит алерт удалено, но из базы то ничего не удалилось. Хотела сделать через урл, но как бы я не указывала путь к сервлету delete все равно выходила ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста, как нужно указать правильно урл, я смотрела здесь http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ и много где, вроде так и сделала, но мой сервлет не видит. Все дело в том что jsp и servlet находятся в разных папках? Так я и папку указывала:(

Comment: О, теперь все! Спасибо, StixoTvorec, за ваше терпение на мои глупые вопросы:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше писать не

```
<a href="javascript:...
```

а просто голую ссылку с неким ID
и уже на этот ID вешать обработку методами JS.
jQuery подключен к странице?

```
<a href="#" id="yes">Yes</a>
<script>
$(document).on('#yes', 'click', function() {
$.ajax(...бла-бла-бла...); //отправка данных
return false; //тут мы говорим, что стандартная реакция на кнопку должна отсутствовать
});
</script>
```

Можно и без jQuery, чистым JS, но так проще.

Читайте про асинхронные запросы.

А вторая ссылка должна вести просто на #.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

P.S.
Решил добавить рабочий пример на jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/admin/manage_categories/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if(parent_id == 0) {

                $child.html(data);
            } else {
                $child.html('');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $child.html('Ошибка при загрузке...');
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {

            $child.html('Подождите...');
        }
    });

});
```

**Обновление**

А все данные Вы можете передать в параметре data аякса.

**Обновление**

Нет-нет. только строгое разделение html и бизнес-логики!
И никаких объектов из js  в серверную часть.
Чтобы удалить данные в БД, Вам нужно знать только ID этих данных.
Вот этот ID и отправьте.
Вам даже форма не нужна - 2 чистых ссылки или кнопки, без разницы.

**Обновление**

Ну, в общем и целом да, можно и объекты отправлять. Хотя это обычно не требуется. И кстати, по умолчанию ajax и так отправляет все в json POST методом (тоже для общего развития).

```
{if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')}
```

Подтверждение можно сделать несколькими способами: переменной с true|false, которая меняет свое значение при первом нажатии; признаком отображения/скрытия предупреждающего текста... С ходу эти 2 вспомнил. Уверен, есть еще.

**Обновление**

Да, путь писать в поле url естественно. Данные на стороне сервера обязательно (обычно) чем-то обработать (экранировать слеши, чтобы избежать инъекций)

**Обновление**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function call() {
var msg = $('#fio');
$.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/echo.jsp',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {variable: 'какие-то данные', id: 'тут ID для удаления'}, // можно было обойтись без variable, но это просто пример
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Удалено');
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

В echo.jsp вы должны принять POST данные (в нашем случае id и variable) и удалить нужное поле (не забываем про безопасность).
Вы принимаете POST данные?

**Обновление**

```
var msg = $('#id').val();

<input type="hidden" id="id" value="<%=dataList5.get(5)%>"/>

data: {id: msg}
```

//забыли `.val()`

//name обычно не требуется, если Вы отправляете данные ajax

//<%=dataList5.get(5)%> - это отдает массив? Тогда в цикле выводите несколько полей ввода, у Вас там что-то невообразимое сейчас скорее всего, если там вывод от массива.

//насколько я понял, Вы выводите записи табличкой? Тогда поставьте на каждой строке свою кнопочку с неким параметром:

```
<a class='btn_del' del_id="1">del 1</a>
<a class='btn_del' del_id="3">del 3</a>
<a class='btn_del' del_id="6">del 6</a>
```

Затем Вы должны обработать нажатия:

```
<script>
$(function(){ //чуть не забыл. Это чтобы подождать построения DOM
  $('a.btn_del').click(function() {
    //$(this) - ссылка, на которую мы нажали
    var id = $(this).attr('del_id'); //данные в атрибутах конечно не приветствуются, но практикуются ;-)
    /// тут уже код ajax, ID мы знаем
    return false; //отключаем реакцию на ссылку
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: А если поставить метод json, то и объекты на сервер полетят

Comment: Ну, я для общего развития отписал. )

Comment: StixoTvorec, спасибо за ответ. Вопрос, а путь на сервлет в поле url прописать? Создать сервлет, который будет делать удаление?

Comment: Так вот здесь у меня выходит алерт удалено, но из базы то ничего не удалилось. Хотела сделать через урл, но как бы я не указывала путь к сервлету delete все равно выходила ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста:(

Comment: Ааа сработало :) Спасибо Вам большое, я просто ссылку делала на сервлет delete.java а не на echo.jsp.

Comment: Я знаю, я достала:( Но еще один вопрос, как сделать чтобы id он менялся, не прописывать же каждый раз id. Делаю var msg который берет id инпута (то есть его значение) Но так не работает.
var msg   = $('#id');
 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<%=dataList5.get(5)%>"/>

Comment: Т.е. мы не вызываем для всех ссылок одну функцию, а просто привязываем к нужным ссылкам обработчик.

P.S. Вопросы не глупые, был рад помочь. Глупыми они были бы, если бы Вы их не задали. Удачи!